# Deploying ASP.NET Core application to ElasticBeanstalk without temporary HTTP 404

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently, ElasticBeanstalk supports ASP.NET Core applications only on Windows platforms (when using the web role), and with Windows-based platform, you can't have Immutable updates or even RollingWithAdditionalBatch for whatever reason. If the application is running with a single instance, you end up with the situation that the only running instance is being updated. (Possible reasons for running a single instance: saving cost because it is just a small backend service, or it might be a service that requires a lot of RAM in comparison to CPU time, so it makes more sense to run one larger instance vs. multiple smaller instances.)

As a result, during deployment of a new application version, for a period of up to 30 seconds, you first get HTTP 503, then HTTP 404, later HTTP 502 Bad Gateway, before the new application version actually becomes available. Obviously this is much worse compared to e.g. using WebDeploy on a single server in a "classic" environment.

Possible workarounds I can think of:

- Blue/Green deployments: slow (because it depends on DNS changes), and it seems like it is more suitable for "supervised" deployments, not for automated deploy pipelines.
- Modify the autoscaling group to enforce 2 active instances before deployment (so that EB can do its normal Rolling update thing), then change back. However it is far from ideal to mess with resources created and managed by EB (like the autoscaling group), and it requires a fairly complex script (you need to wait for the second instance to become active, need to wait for rolling deployment etc.).

I can't believe that this are the only options. Any other ideas? The minimal viable workaround for me would be to at least get rid of the temporary 404s because this could seriously mislead API clients (or think of the SEO effect in case of a website if a search engine spider gets a 404 for every URL). As long as it is 5xx at least everybody knows it is just a temporary error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, in Feb 2019, AWS released Elastic Beanstalk Windows Server platform v2, which supports *Immutable* und *Rolling with an additional Batch* deployments and platform updates (like their Linux-based stacks already supported for ages):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/relnotes/release-2019-02-21-windows-v2.html

This solves the problem even for environments (normally) running just one instance.